# Add event record into Google calendar by email

Tags: email, events, calendar, notifications

How to send email-notification that will add an event. Using [this tool](http://gmail-actions.appspot.com/) I sent "event card" to my Gmail and receive an email as well as notification about adding a new event to my calendar. But if I try to send this exactly "event card" content via PHP, for example, than I receive an email, but not new event in my calendar. What am I doing wrong?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="application/ld+json">
    {
      "@context": "http://schema.org",
      "@type": "EventReservation",
      "reservationNumber": "E123456789",
      "underName": {
        "@type": "Person",
        "name": "Andrii Tarykin"
      },
      "modifiedTime": "2013-11-02T13:15:00-08:00",
      "modifyReservationUrl": "http://gmail-actions.appspot.com/success/{{token}}",
      "reservationStatus": "confirmed",
      "reservationFor": {
        "@type": "Event",
        "name": "Foo Fighters Concert",
        "performer": {
          "@type": "Person",
          "name": "Metallica",
          "image": "http://example.com"
        },
        "startDate": "2015-10-01T13:07:55",
        "location": {
          "@type": "Place",
          "name": "AT&T Park",
          "address": {
            "@type": "PostalAddress",
            "streetAddress": "24 Willie Mays Plaza",
            "addressLocality": "San Francisco",
            "addressRegion": "CA",
            "postalCode": "94107",
            "addressCountry": "US"
          }
        }
      }
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      This a test for an Event reservation Google Now card in Gmail.
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

This code doesn't work for me, it doesn't add event in my calendar.